# 32-bit signed words in mips

Tags: assembly, binary, mips, signed

I am trying to write a simple mips program and I'm stuck on declaring a 32-bit signed integer.

I've written the following simple code:

```
.data
max: .word 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

I expect the value of max to be -1 but my IDE tells me that the number is being interpreted as -954437177. I am using MARS 4.4 as my IDE.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get mips to actually recognize the value as -1?

Comment: I don't know why it's being interpreted as ` -954437177`, but I'm pretty sure that `11111111111111111111111111111111` isn't going to be interpreted as a binary number.  Why not try `-1` instead since that's what you want?

Comment: That's a big decimal number, which when converted to binary and truncated to 32 bits, is `-954437177`.

Comment: I am writting this for an assignment and the assignment said: "Write a MIPS program, using a loop, which computes the maximum of five consecutive (32-bit) words in memory (treating the words as two's complement integers) and stores the result in a word labeled max." For this reason I was trying to write 32-bit binary values. Is there no way to do this? Am I understanding the assignment incorrectly? @Jester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.word puts the number into decimal, and when you convert it, since its 32-bit, you will only get last 32 bit.
11111111111111111111111111111111(10)=
10001100001111011110111110110001111011011011100110000100111111100010101011000111000111000111000111000111(2)

last 32-bit: 11000111000111000111000111000111(2) = -954437177
If you want to store -1 as 32-bit, try 
.word 0xFFFFFFFF which has a value of -1

Comment: Is there a difference between doing .word 0xFFFFFFFF or .word -1?

Comment: to be honest i do not know if "-" is allowed there, you can try.

Comment: It seems to compile fine and not give me any errors. Will mips interpret this value correctly or is it better to use a hexadecimal representation?

Comment: i would use hexadecimal, the reason is it is going to be converted into binary at the machine code level where you do not have the '-' sign, maybe the compiler is smart enough to convert '-' but i prefer using hex